# % doesn't work after rand() c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, random, visual-studio-2015

I have to use fmod function instead of % on this code:

```
int prob = rand();// % 4;
    prob = fmod(prob,4);
    if (prob == 0) {
        shoot = true;
    }
    else shoot = false;
```

if I use %, prob variable it doesn't get any value on debuger.

Second problem is it never gets inside if, I put breakpoint on if, another on else, and other on shoot = true;
the debuger says: The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No executable code of the debugger's target code type is associated.

On other computer the second problem doesn't exist.

Full function:

```
void cVoladorEstatico::Logic(int *map)
{

    double t1 = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);
    if (t1 - moveDelaySteering > 20 * 20) {
        random_variable = rand();
        moveDelaySteering = t1;
    }
    if (t1 - moveDelay > 20) {
        int aux = y;

        y += random_variable%speed - 3;

        //Whats next tile?
        if ((y % TILE_SIZE) <= 1)
        {

            /*y += speedY;
            x += speedX;*/
            //si choca con tile, se autodestruye muy fuerte
            if (CollidesMapWall(map, false)) y = aux; //delete this;
        }
        //Advance, no problem
        else
        {
            /*y += speedY;
            x += speedX;*/
            //TODO: si choca, hace magia
        }
        moveDelay = t1;
    }
    //should i shoot
    //if (t1 - lastShootDec > shootChance) {
    int prob = rand();// % 4;
    prob = fmod(prob,4);
    if (prob == 0) {
        shoot = true;
    }
    else shoot = false;
    //}
}
```

Comment: Did you recompile your code?

Comment: Why would you use `fmod` on an `int`?

Comment: You should use `(value & 3)` rather than using `%` or `fmod`.  Some compilers may code `& 3` more efficiently than `% 4`, depending on optimization levels.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews: Quite the opposite. If you need a remainder, it is `%`, not `&`. Avoid using `&` at all costs, if you need a remainder specifically. Any compiler that would fail to generate identical, most efficient code for `%` and `&` in situations where they are equivalent, would be laughed off the market very quickly. However, for signed types `%` and `&` are generally not equivalent.

Comment: In the original code, the debugger is probably lying to you. There's a good chance that the optimizer removed the `prob` variable, since it is used **only** in the condition of the `if` statement. Try writing out the value of `prob` to see what's really going on. The original code should work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original code should work just fine. Chances are the debugger isn't telling you the truth; any good optimizer will skip storing the value into `prob`, since it's **only** used in the condition of the `if` statement. So write out the value after computing `prob` to see what's going on.